# extract specific cell from database & calculate, webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I am currently working with Webmatrix, attempting to design a web app. I am trying to create a site that allows users to analyze data from a database using graphs. I have created a database from which I would like to extract the int value from within a particular cell and multiply it with another, then  graph the output, much like an Excel sheet does. In fact, I have an excel sheet that I am basically trying to turn into an interactive web app.

I am running into an issue when trying to graph the result. Below is code that I have tried.

@{

```
var db = Database.Open("myDatabase") ;
var sql = "SELECT myFirstColumn FROM myDatabase WHERE Id = 5";
var fifth = db.QueryValue(sql);
sql = "SELECT mySecondColumn FROM myDatabase WHERE Id = 6";
var sixth = db.QueryValue(sql);
var calculation = sixth * fifth;
var grid = new WebGrid(calculation);
```

}

Also, I have tried to leave out the WebGrid() by creating a var Chart, then using the write() function. This has also failed. I am creating all of this within a .cshtml page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If anyone feels that I am taking the wrong route by using Webmatrix to create this sort of web app, please let me know and tell me what language/platform would be best. I am open to learning a new platform and/or language if needed. I don't want to waste too much time before realizing I'm taking the wrong route. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the following code:

```
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("My Chart"
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Calculations",
            xValue: new[] {  fifth },
            yValues: new[] { calculation })
        .Write();
```

What did the chart code you referred to as failing do?

Comment: That works to display the chart with all values in the fifth column and the calculation column but where I'm running into the problem is calculating a single "cell" with another, then graphing the result. for instance, lets say i have the value "5" located in column 1 with Id = 1, and I want to multiply it with the value "10" located in column 2 with id =2. The result would be 50, which is the point I want the graph to display. Think of an excel sheet, and the way 3

Comment: server side database calculations possibly the answer?